# What is the error and how can I fix it please?

Tags: php

Notice: Function is_post_type_archive was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/rideiukw/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on [image]

Comment: The code in the screenshot only tells you where the error was triggered, not where the faulty code is. Have you done any custom coding on your site? Check any files you've updated and do a search for "is_post_type_archive". Alternatively, you can turn on [WP_DEBUG](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to get a better idea of what the problem is.